# How to merge same user data from multiple social logins.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, devise, omniauth, facebook-login

I am using omni-auth so that user can authenticate using both Facebook or/and Linkedin.

Now some users would use the same email id for db,lnkd registration. My user table enforces that the email should be unique for a user.

So if an already registered user through one social network could not login through other social network

I am using Rails with devise and omni-auth gems.

Now with omni-auth and social logins:
 1] There is no unique attribute for a user (email could be multiple etc)
 2] There is no way of determining same user with fb and linkedin logins are actually the same user.

Rails, 
In general loads a lot of user data into user object so it might be tricky to work with gems if user is not actually a user model.

**1] How do I create a user table without a single unique element ?**

**2] How are the sites like Quora, Airbnb etc handling this ?**

**3] Seems like a very common problem. Any gems I can look at ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you know you will not use any other omniauth-* gems, you could change your user table to include the fields `facebook_uid` and `linkedin_uid`. Otherwise, you should create a generic `authentications` table with the fields `user_id`, `provider` and `uid`. You would then change your user model to have a `has_many :authentications` relationship.

These Railscasts should help you:

- [OmniAuth Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)
- [OmniAuth Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)

But be aware of the **security implications** of merging accounts/giving access to same account using different providers. [See here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109346/can-facebook-omniauth-email-address-be-securely-trusted/20111506#20111506).

Comment: Thanks @Ashitaka , I like the approach of having a separate authentications table. I was using devise already and it requires to have class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController       .. while the tutorial mentions to use class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController  .. Any suggestion on how this should be structured while using devise ?

Comment: Just keep using `OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => {:scope => :provider}
```

There is no need of redesigning the schema and I'm not aware of any issue.

To replace the Devise email index you can do:

```
add_index "users", ["email", "provider"], :name => "index_users_on_email_provider", :unique => true
```

Comment: Thanks @CV-Gate for the update. So for a given users, its possible that there would be more than one entries in the User table ? (one per provider) ? This would not be normalized ?