# Facebook login via app with unverified user account in FB

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook-ios-sdk-3.10, Using this SDK I'll login and fetch user details from FB Its working fine for me.

This is the code I'm uisng

```
- (IBAction)fbLogin_click:(id)sender
{
    if (AppDelegate.fbsession.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"email", @"publish_stream", @"read_stream",@"read_friendlists",@"manage_friendlists",@"friends_about_me",@"publish_actions", nil];

        // create a session object, with defaults accross the board, except that we provide a custom
        // instance of FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy
        AppDelegate.fbsession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                                                   permissions:permissions
                                               urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                            tokenCacheStrategy:nil]; 
    }


    FBSessionLoginBehavior behavior = FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView; 
    if (AppDelegate.fbsession.state != FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

        // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
        [AppDelegate.fbsession openWithBehavior:behavior completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                           FBSessionState status,
                                                                           NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }

            [self GetFBUserDetails];
        }];      
    }
} 

-(void) GetFBUserDetails
{
    if (AppDelegate.fbsession.isOpen)
    {
        [HUD show:YES];
        // fetch profile info such as name, id, etc. for the open session
        FBRequest *me = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:AppDelegate.fbsession graphPath:@"me"];

        self.pendingRequest= me;

        [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                         NSError *error) {
            // because we have a cached copy of the connection, we can check
            // to see if this is the connection we care about; a prematurely
            // cancelled connection will short-circuit here
            if (me != self.pendingRequest) {
                return;
            }

            self.pendingRequest = nil;
            //            self.pendingLoginForSlot = -1;

            // we interpret an error in the initial fetch as a reason to
            // fail the user switch, and leave the application without an
            // active user (similar to initial state)
            if (error) {

                return;
            }

            [AppDelegate.fbsession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [FBSession.activeSession close];
            [FBSession.activeSession  closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            FBSession.activeSession=nil;

            [self FacebookCustomerRegister:user];
        }];
    }
}
```

In such case some user create Facebook account and not very his account through email, when he try to login via my app it shows empty screen after click login button, there is no action further. how can I notify the user "You not yet verify your FB account" and it not return to my app. how can I fetch the response from there ? refer screen short.

[image]

[image]

I give login details, after click login button that blank screen will appear after this no response from SDK and not return to App.

can anyone help me for this ?

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

read more :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial

Comment: I already done this, but still its not working

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    return ([FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:self.fbsession] ||
            [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]);
}