# When email returned is it guaranteed to be verified?

Tags: passport.js, facebook-oauth

When designing a social sign-on, I want to use Facebook as one of the providers.

When requesting the optional property `email` and users agree to share it, is this email-address guaranteed to be verified? If not, is there an parameter returned in the social-profile that tells me if it's verified?

I'd like to do email verification myself otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check if an email is confirmed on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook)