# Why would the Facebook auth callback from omniauth-facebook not be returning the email and UID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

Certain users in our application reported not being able to log in via their Facebook account. I looked into it and was able to repro an issue where the callback hash doesn't contain the uid or the email. Here's an example of the hash:

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=1409288689 token="CAALQVOrveN4BAHwlBhXvuefS1m7KIq0mWZCGrXslpbrsp4SJXMZBTj2ZC7T8YJHMA8QCywws91I4ZCZCj0oUZAAzkJuwYuHvsRUUEZBnUSnAxpbSuOJZCuKXpWZBZAeHkjcIR0IQCorkFTvV4BGu9UcN8hnEeaWST5DTjOR5lkRvVTsijlPSokvwgD"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info="\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xB5Vmo\xDB6\x10\xFE+\x84>\xEC\xCB\xEC\x84\xAF\x92\x98oi\x82\x0E\xED\xD6\xB5H2\x04\xC5\\\x04\x8Ct\x8E8\xCB\xA4F\xD11\x9C\xA2\xFF}G%\xA9\x99\x97\r\x18\xB0\x01\xB6\x00\x91w\xC7\xBB\xE7y\xEE\xA8\xAF\x85m\x8B\xA3BiJ\xA9\x94\xBC\x98\x15\xB06\xB6\xC7\xA5\xA6\x19\x9Bnm\xE3\xDDb\x83[\xF4&-\x1F4~\x8D&Ks\xEB\x83\x8Dpeb\xD7C\x84\xB18\xFA\xFD\xEB} F\x19\xA5\x82J!X]q\x86\xC6\xCE\xAC\x017\xCE\xCC\x8E\x1C\xF7=\xB8\xE2\xDB\xEC\xC1\xB6\xD2\x1A\x7FLh\x9D\xCE}\xB0;\xDD\xEE\x8C\x03riZ\xD8[\x96\xB2*\xA9\xD6RK\x9AE\xF47\x10\xC8[h!@\xC8l\xB9\xAE\x14\xC6dZ\xECm?\xD8\xA63\xD0\x93\xF7>\xB4&K\x81\xD1\x92\xD6T2-\xB9\xD0e\x96\xEE\xB1\t\xDE\x913\xDF\xE2\x19cn\xAFJ\xC6j)\x98\xCCR\xF6\xCE\xF4-9\r\xF66%\xF2%\x03(\x82Yg\xE8HEkQ+\xC4:\xAB\xF8\x83\xED\xB7f\xB3\x02 o\x02l\x9F\x1E\xA7YM\x95\xE45+_\xB5\xDF4\xAB\xCC\xBAbe\xC54U\xB4\xCA\xA2\xFF\x14\x00\x1Cy\x83\xE8\x7F2\xCDj\x8A\x9E\x12\xB4a\x8CW\x0F&']\xB0#z\xDC\x80C,qamz\xC0\xF7\xCE\xAF!\xFA\xAD+\x8E\xBEW/\xAARh\xCE\xB5V\x9Cg\b\x1C\x0F\x03\xEA\xC0\xBB\x19\xB9\xB4c\xE3\xDDh\x13\xC6\x85u\xE3`\x83\x896\x01t5\x80G\xAB\\*\x92I\xCA\xEB\x92\xD7\xB5\x92\xD5>\xDA{\xDF!\xF40\xDA\x9B\f\x89J\xD6\xA5\xD6TsZ\x89:\xAB\xEF3t\x9B\xD6\x90\x9FM\xBC\x9B*\xEB\xCD\xBE\xB0\xF3{\x01\xA3qo\xDD\n\x17\xBA\x18\x87\xF1hq\xB88\xDCn\xB7\aK\xD3\xC0\xB5\xF7\xAB\xA4\xEA\xC5\xE1w\xBD's\xDFLY\xEF+g\\\n\x84\xB6\xAE*\xA6\x9E\xC8\x15\xC8'\xD4\xDF\xB3\xC2\x93\x7F*\xB5\x00w\xF5\xDB\xF9\xDEzB\x9A\xEC\xD3\x1A|o\xA3E\xDB\xB4\x87\xDE\x10n\xF1\xDC\xDB\x04~\x80\xDE\xDEL)\xDC{E\x8B\xBA\x9D\x15\xE3\xE0C|\xD2o5GV*\x9D\x9E*\x13\xF0\xB9_\xC6k\xD3\xF7\xB9v\xB5(\xEB\xAA\xE6\x92sQe\xEC\x9Dm\x9C\xB3.\x03[2\x81\x12\x15Z\xC9\x1A\x9FY\xCB]\x00Z\x8E\x04;\xE3\xED\x03v\x13\xE6\x7Fn\xFC4\x04\x8AE\xF1\xD9\x90\x95\xF3[\xB2\xEDL$\xB1\x83\x1D\x19\xCD\xEE\xE0\xE0\x80\x90w\xCB\xF4N\xC6\xCE\x03Y\xDA8\xCEH\f;bc\x8Af\\\x8B\x9B\xC8\x111\xD7~\x13quQ\x90995\x0E\xDB\xCFoFr\n\xC6\x91\xF3\xCE\xF4\xAB\x0E_Q\xA4\xB3\"\xDA5\xDCy\x87i\xCD\xD5\xAC\xD8\f\xAD\x89\xD0^\xA5UL\x84S&\xE7\xB4\x9C\xB3\xEA\x82\xF3#Q\x1EQ\xF5#\x96\x94JI\xEE\x0F\xE5\xE4\x94c\xEB\xDA\xA5\x05,?\x86\r\xCC\x8A\xAD\x0F\xAB\tfX\x0F\xBD\xDF\xA5\xBEx@\x87\xEB\x922\xC1q\xC8\x958\a\xB2!s\t\x1F\xBC\x8B\xE6&\r\xAEW$DK\xC6+\xEC\xCDJq-\xD5\xDE\xEDWlP\xD3=S\xD0\xE0G\xFB\xC4\x1D+\xE2\x8C\xE3p\xD3eU\xD6\x99\xFB\xC9\xC5G\xF2\x039\xF1\x88\xD7\xD2o\xA6\x0EF\xFF1\x9A\x10\xAF\x12&\xF7\xBE\"\xA1A\xD9\xC4\xF1\x8B\x8A\x98\xAA\xB0\xAB1\xBB\xAA\x948\x103u\xA3\x04\xA3\xE9q\xC8\x86h{{w\x1F\xFBen\x8A\n\x81\x7F\x96\xCASY'\x9F\xF8\xF9\xDB\x7F\xCCI<\xE6\xD4\xC2\xD8\x04;\xDC\x87-\xDE\xA1\xCB\x90\xA6\x91\x8Bd\v\xD7\xA4\x85[\xE8\xFD\x80\xE3>)%\xA1\xB4\xE9\xA3q\xF1\xA0H\xF7\xD5\xB3j\x14+\xB1'\xB4\xAA\x85\xAEe\xCE\xCF\x93\xEE#\xBF\xFCr\xF2:O\xFF\xAE\xD5_\x80\xC1\x18\x82\xC0q\xCCk\xA5\xA8\xCA\xFC?n\xDD\xDF\xE2\xC0\xBEs\xE3\xDA\xC7\x9D\xA4\xD7\xF9$\xD9\x17%J,N\xF2twUx\xD5\xD6Y\x83b\x87\x9D\x04\xBCt \xEC\xFE\xBB\xEC\xF8\xEB,!\xBB\x93\x17\xF1\xCB\x84L\x03\xD3F\x02vF\fY\x9B\xB0\x82\x88s\x05\xF9Z\x0F\xC6\xEDP\x9E\x81\x8Cx\xB7\xF4\xE4z\x83\xE8\xC18\xC2\x88m\x8F\x83b\x1C\xA0\xB1&\tl$\xD6M\x94'\xA2\x87`Q\x00m\xBA\t\xDCD\xF5\x1E\x9C\xD4\x0Es6%\xF6\n>B\xE2\xB7\x8C\x16\xA9\xD52\xFE\xF79\xFE/\xC4s\x81\x13\x13\x8F,\xCBJ(\xA9\x9FA\xBB8\xBC\x84\xEB\xD3G\x1DO\x01\x82\xFF\x03\x9A|\x98\xF3\n\xBFBx\xC5\x90\x1F\xAADb\xFE)\xE0\xC7\xE4\x12\xBF_>\x05D.\xCD\xD2\xF54M\x87\x84\xCC\x9E\xFE5\x9C\xC1\x12-:\\\xDD\xDA\xD8\xED\xA3+Q*IE\xFE\tu\x81W\xBC\x19\xC9\e\x9B\xE2\xE0(O\xC3\xFC\x19\xFFT?v\xE9\x97o\x7F\x01\x16\a+3-\n\x00\x00"> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash image="http://graph.facebook.com//picture"> provider="facebook" uid=nil>
```

Notice at the end, the `info` hash doesn't contain the `email` field or a valid `image` URL. This response is for my account (I am an admin for the FB app) and I am getting this in development and production. Tested on a handful of other accounts though and it seems to be working for most.

Comment: [Facebook will only return an email if it has been confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook). I'm not sure about the missing UID though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I just confirmed that my email is confirmed :)

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because of low rep however, could it be down to permissions they have set on their facebook accounts. Here is a a section taken from their docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I don't think that's the problem because I am specifically asking for the user's email on the auth request.