# Verified email address from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to be certain that email addresses returned from the Facebook graph API have been verified by the owner of the email address. The same question was asked here: [Is it possible to check if an email is confirmed on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook) where the conclusion seems to be: yes, they are verified. However, I cannot find this anywhere in the API documentation. Can someone point me in the direction of official documentation around this?

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation but they are verified.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do the verification yourself:

> If you use an email address as the unique credential which identifies each account, your app should verify that the email address associated with the person's Facebook account (and obtained during Facebook Login) is valid. You can do this by creating code in your app to send a verification email to the address obtained after Facebook Login (you will probably need to have this step as part of your regular login system anyway).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers#postfb1

Answer (score -2):

It's in the Graph API User, verified field.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: No, that's account verification state. I'm looking specifically for email address verification. From the documentation on "verified": 

Indicates whether the account has been verified. This is distinct from the is_verified field. Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions:
Register for mobile
Confirm their account via SMS
Enter a valid credit card